# The usage of Pattern, Matcher, replace

Tags: java, design-patterns, matcher

I want to remove quotation marks of sentences.

ex)
Sackler Gallery postpones controversial “Shipwreck” show
-> Sackler Gallery postpones controversial Shipwreck show

I know that's possible using Patter - Matcher - replace.
But I don't know how to use it.

```
static String getText(String content) {
  Pattern NOQMARK = Pattern.compile("A");
  Matcher m;
  m = SCRIPTS.matcher(content);   
  content = m.replaceAll("");

  return content
}
```

What should I put in "A"?

Any suggestion would be helpful for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about simply

```
String result = input.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: Or even `input.replace("\"", "")`.  There is no need for a regular expression.